# The polynomial $a z^n+z+1$ has at least one root in $|z| \leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am trying to solve this problem, but I don't have any idea.

The problem is:

Prove that for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \geqslant 2$, polynomial $P(z) = a z^n+z+1$ has at least one root inside the disc $S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \leqslant 2 \}$.

Does anyone have idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Rouche's theorem?

Comment: I found that theorem, but have no idea how to use it to solve the problem..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result follows immediately if $a=0$, so suppose $a \neq 0$.

The product of the zeros of the polynomial

$$
P(z) = az^n + z + 1 = a \left(z^n + \frac{1}{a} z + \frac{1}{a} \right)
$$

is $(-1)^n/a$. If all $n$ zeros of $P$ satisfy $|z| > 2$ then this product must be greater than $2^n$ in absolute value.  In other words, this would imply that

$$
\frac{1}{|a|} > 2^n,
$$

which is equivalent to $|a| < 2^{-n}$. Consequently,

> If $|a| \geq 2^{-n}$ then $P$ must have a zero in the disk $|z| \leq 2$.

This is part of what was asked. We need to use a different argument to handle the values of $a$ satisfying $|a| < 2^{-n}$.

Suppose that $|a| < 2^{-n}$.  Then on the circle $|z| = 2$ we have

$$
|az^n| = |a|2^n < 1
$$

and

$$
|z+1| \geq |z| - |1| = 1,
$$

so that $|az^n| < |z+1|$. By Rouché's theorem we conclude that the polynomial

$$
az^n+z+1 = P(z)
$$

has as many zeros inside $|z| = 2$ as does the polynomial $z+1$, which is one. Restated,

> If $|a| < 2^{-n}$ then $P$ has exactly one zero in the disk $|z| < 2$.

Combining these conclusions yields the desired result, that

> For arbitrary $a \in \mathbb C$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ with $n \geq 2$, the polynomial $P(z) = az^n + z + 1$ has at least one zero in the disk $|z| \leq 2$.

It's worth noting that if $a=(-2)^{-n}$ then $P$ has a zero at $z=-2$ and no zeros inside $|z| < 2$, so this bound is sharp.

Comment: Antonio Vargas, thank you very, very much.. I only want to ask you for your second conclusion yield.. Does it need to be |z|<2 or |z|=2 ?

Comment: Rouche's theorem states that if $|f(z)| < |g(z)|$ on $|z| = r$ then $f(z)+g(z)$ has the same number of zeros as $g(z)$ in $|z| < r$.  This is why the second conclusion involves $|z| < 2$ after using Rouche's theorem with the circle $|z| = 2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much..

Comment: I think the product of the zeros of the polynomial is $\frac{(-1)^n}{a}$ not $\frac{1}{a}$, but that doesn't affect the proof. I just mention it.

Comment: @MathewJames quite right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem and think about what you could use for f and g (this will depend on $\alpha$). Try choosing f,g so that f + g is the equation want.

Comment: Thanks.. I have never earlier used this theorem, so I am not sure how can I choose functions, can I choose f=a z^n and g=z+1 ?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to start! Have a look at when f and g satisfy what you need in the theorem.

Comment: I suppose that these functions are holomorphic, that means they are differentiable, but I am not sure how to prove this. And also I think that the second condition is satisfied |g|<|f|... Am I right?

Comment: They are indeed holomorphic since they are polynomials, |g| < |f| may hold but it depends on $\alpha$, try and work out what $\alpha$ must satisfy.

Comment: thank you very much.. so, if I understand you, I need to limit $a$ so that is $|g|<|f|$ and for that $a$ I need to see how many roots has $f$, and $f+g$ has the same number of roots?

Comment: I didn't succeed to limit $a$, can you help me?  $|g|<|f| ;$
$|z+1|<|az^n|, \: \: \: z=x+iy ;$
$|x+iy|<|a(x+iy)^n| ;$
$|x+iy|<|a||{n \choose 0} x^n + {n \choose 1} x^{n-1}(iy)^1 + {n \choose 2} x^{n-2}(iy)^2+...+{n \choose {n-1}} x (iy)^{n-1} + {n \choose n}(iy)^n |$
$ \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} < |a||  \sum_{k=0, k=4l}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} -
\sum_{k=0, k=4l+2}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} + \\
+ i \sum_{k=0, k=4l+1}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} - 
i \sum_{k=0, k=4l+3}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k}|, \: \: l \in \mathbb{N}  
$

Comment: I think the new answer from Antonio should clear things up! :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much in any case.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Take *f(z)=1* and *g(z)=az^n+z* such that *|f(z)|<|g(z)|* inside S. Hence by Rouche's theorem *f(z)+g(z)* and *g(z)* has same number of zeroes (including multiplicity) inside S. As g(z) has a zero at *z=0* which is always inside S, hence the result.

Comment: It is not true that $|az^n + z| > 1$ for all $a \in \mathbb C$ and $n \geq 2$. Take, for example, $n=2$ and $a = 1/2$. Then at $z=-2$ we have $$|g(z)| = |az^n+z| = 0 < 1 = |f(z)|.$$ In general, for any given $n$ the statement "$|az^n+z| > 1$ on $|z| = 2$" is false when $a=2^{1-n}$.